# How can I manage and limit disk usage for each author?

Tags: uploads, author, media, user-roles

I want display and limit disk usage for each author and be able to manage disk usage as an administrator.

Example: author1: disk space is 20Mb; if they uploaded more 20Mb the upload button (in media library and post) is disabled.

author2: disk space is 30Mb,  if they upload more 30Mb the upload button (in media library and post) is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Okey so this is just an example how you can archive this..

First change the upload directory to the current users username. eg uploads/admin

```
function wpse_16722_type_upload_dir( $args ) {
    // Get current user data
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Make upload dir to current username
    $newdir = '/' . $current_user->user_login;

    $args['path']    = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['path'] ); //remove default subdir
    $args['url']     = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['url'] );      
    $args['subdir']  = $newdir;
    $args['path']   .= $newdir; 
    $args['url']    .= $newdir; 

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_16722_type_upload_dir' );
```

Then we need a function to check the size of the current users uploads. I found a function called `recurse_dirsize` within [ms-functions.php](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/ms-functions.php) that calculate the directory in bytes.

```
/**
 * Get the size of a directory recursively.
 *
 * Used by get_dirsize() to get a directory's size when it contains
 * other directories.
 *
 * @since MU
 *
 * @param string $directory
 * @return int
 */
function recurse_dirsize( $directory ) {
    $size = 0;

    $directory = untrailingslashit( $directory );

    if ( !file_exists($directory) || !is_dir( $directory ) || !is_readable( $directory ) )
        return false;

    if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
        while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
            $path = $directory.'/'.$file;
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                if (is_file($path)) {
                    $size += filesize($path);
                } elseif (is_dir($path)) {
                    $handlesize = recurse_dirsize($path);
                    if ($handlesize > 0)
                        $size += $handlesize;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $size;
}
```

And then we need to check if the current users uploads is bigger than x if so disable `media_buttons`

```
function wpse_16722_user_upload_size() {
    // Get current user data
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Array of key => value pairs
    $uploads = wp_upload_dir(); 

    $dir = $uploads['basedir'] . '/' .  $current_user->user_login;

    if( file_exists( $dir ) && is_dir( $dir ) ) {
        $size = recurse_dirsize( $dir ) / 1024 / 1024;

        // Convert bytes to human readable format
        $new_size = round( $size / 1024 * 1024, 2 );

        // If current users upload dir is
        // Bigger than 20 MB disable
        // Upload buttton
        if( $new_size  >= 20 ) {
            remove_action( 'media_buttons', 'media_buttons' );
        }


    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'wpse_16722_user_upload_size');
```

You also wanted to control more than one user and different sizes. I would recommend you to add a settings-page that saves the users available size with `update_user_meta($user_id, 'size_limit', $value );` Read more about that [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)

When you have the sizes added to the `users_meta` you can change the size within the function `wpse_16722_user_upload_size` "20" to the size within `get_user_meta( $user_id, 'size_limit');`

Comment: Great solution with `uploads/username`. Applaud.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this function disable media buttons
function removemediabuttons()
{
   remove_action( 'media_buttons', 'media_buttons' );
}

// this function check the total size of all attachments by user. 
//But it doesnt count sizes of thumbnails. 
// $limitBytes -- maximum size in bytes
function checkMidiaSizeByUser($userId, $limitBytes) 
{
    // get all attachments of $userId
    $attachements = query_posts(
      array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'author' => $userId
      )
    );
    // count size
    $size = 0;
    foreach($attachements as $attachment){
      $size += filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment->ID ) );
    }
    // check limit
    if ( $size >= $limitBytes ) {
      add_action('admin_head','removemediabuttons');
    }
}

/* **************************************** */

// Set our limit to 20Mb
$limit = 20*1024*1024; 

// get current user
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo(); 

//check limit and disable media buttons if user met limit
checkMidiaSizeByUser($current_user->ID, $limit);
```

I don't test this code in real work, but it should work.

Comment: although I have not tested, but I think it runs fine, however I would like to thank you very much for answering my question.thank you very much

Comment: It would be nice if you select the best answer and "solve" your question in this way.

Comment: oh, it run, but submenu media libary ( add media ) don't diasbale. and it can't manager by user. because more users, i want disk space differant and easy manager ( change disk space each user ),i think manager by list user by page .about one list user and disk space corresponding. i look for. I look forward to receiving feedback from you soon

Comment: i saw errors, the home page don't show pages & posts true and website run not true. wp admin can't show list post & page.

Comment: i tried fix errors, i add code <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> and fixed. but i can't manager disk space each user.i think manager in profile user. help me